# Python function minimization not changing optimization variables

Tags: python, optimization, scipy-optimize-minimize, jax

I need to minimize a simple function that divides two values. The optimization paramter `x` is a `(n,m)` numpy array from which I calculate a float.

```
# An initial value
normX0 = calculate_normX(x_start)

def objective(x) -> float:
    """Objective function """
    x = x.reshape((n,m))
    normX = calculate_normX(x)
    return -(float(normX) / float(normX0))
```

`def calculate_normX()` is a wrapper function to an external (Java-)API that takes the *ndarray* as an input and outputs a *float*, in this case, the norm of a vector. For the optimization, I was using `jax` and `jaxopt`, since it supports automatic differentiation of `objective`.

```py
solver = NonlinearCG(fun=objective, maxiter=5, verbose=True)
res = solver.run(x.flatten())
```

or the regular scipy minimize

```py
objective_jac = jax.jacrev(objective)
minimize(objective, jac=objective_jac, x0=`x.flatten(), method='L-BFGS-B', options={'maxiter': 2})
```

In both cases, however, `x` is not changed during the optimization step. Even initializing x with random values the optimizer does not seem to work. I also tried other solvers like  [Jaxopt NonlinearCG](https://jaxopt.github.io/stable/_autosummary/jaxopt.NonlinearCG.html#jaxopt.NonlinearCG). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I propose creating minimal reproducible example. Also, put breakpoint in your objective function and check what solver inputs as x, are output values sane, non-nan/inf

Comment: I doubt that it's a good idea to ask Java for a norm when numpy can almost certainly do that

Comment: A working example is hard to give, since I almost doubt, that anyone can mimic the external call (which is a call to a FEM/Comsol Multiphysics). That the function is named norm has nothing to do with Java or NumPy's norm function. It's called that way due to the simple fact, that it gives back the norm, but this relies on a previous Simulation of a field, thus python is indeed not capable of calculating the norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external, non-JAX function call is almost certainly the source of the problem. Non-JAX function calls within JAX transforms like `jacrev` effectively get replaced with a trace-time constant (and in most cases will error), and so it makes sense that your optimization will not change its value.

The best approach would be to define your `calculate_normX` function using JAX rather than calling out to an external API, and then everything should work automatically.

If you must call to an external API, one way to do this in JAX is to use `pure_callback` along with `custom_jvp` to define the autodiff rule for your external callback. There is an example of this in the JAX docs: https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/external_callbacks.html#example-pure-callback-with-custom-jvp